# How to have separate cookies for each tab in geckofx C#?

Tags: c#, session, cookies, geckofx

I started working with geckofx and implemented a simple browser with tabs. My question is how do I manage to give each tab a separate cookie/session id?

**Edit:** Or is it possible to create a new instance of the browser with new cookies?

Answer (score 1):

Solution: If a Siterefresh is not intended, this works good: [Is that possible ? GeckoFX can use seperate CookieContainer per instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20209756/is-that-possible-geckofx-can-use-seperate-cookiecontainer-per-instance/20227011#20227011)

Following the code you put in and let visual studio complete the interface implementation.

```
[Guid("c375fa80-150f-11d6-a618-0010a401eb10")]
[ContractID(CookieServiceFactory.ContractID)]
public class CookieServiceFactory : GenericOneClassNsFactory<CookieServiceFactory, CookieService>
{
    public const string ContractID = "@mozilla.org/cookieService;1";
}
public class CookieService : nsICookieManager2
{
    private static nsICookieManager2 _cookieService;

    static CookieService()
    {
        _cookieService = Xpcom.GetService<nsICookieManager2>(Contracts.CookieManager);
    }
```